# Using "heretofore" in the past perfect

Tags: verbs, past-tense, past-participles, past-perfect

Is it grammatically correct to use "heretofore" in the past perfect?

> ...the king's power, which had heretofore been absolute.

The meaning of "heretofore" is "before now", but would it still work in the past?

What I really want to say is "before then." Is there a word for that, or would "heretofore" still work for that?

Comment: The obvious choice seems to be *theretofore*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend *theretofore*, being of the same construction as *heretofore* and meaning *before that time*.

Answer (score 0):

> In a narrative, you could certainly use "hitherto" or theretofore", though they both sound formal and "theretofore" is considered obsolete. Whether you choose the Past Simple or the Past Perfect will depend on context. You might as well use "until then", "before that time", "previously", etc. if your intention is not to create a medieval atmosphere.

Comment: What do you mean by obsolete? I use *hitherto* regularly in written form. It is in everyday use in Britain. 'Theretofore' I have never used and seldom seen used.